# Html ordered list ol, add space between number and text

Tags: html

I want to add space between number of ordered list and text

ex :

```
 1.     Hello.
 2.     Test.
```

Space between "1." and "Hello" needs to be increased.

Note: I'm using below style, because i want no. to start with left most

```
    ol
    {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
    li
    {       
        list-style-position: inside;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

I want exactly like below image, im able to get everything other than the space between numbering of list and text(marked in the image)
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that you had `.li` instead of `li` in your code

```css
ol {
  word-break: break-all;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ol ol {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
}
li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello.
    Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello.</li>
  <li>Test.</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Hello.Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello. Hello.</li>
    <li>Test.</li>
  </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sorry pls chek the image ive updated, i want exactly like that

Comment: @ManojShenoy works fine, or do you want it diffrent?

Comment: Sir, I want it to start from left most and the next line should start below the no.
Ex: if the sentence of point  "1" goes to new line, the line should start below "1", Thanks for support

in your code "1" starts after 5-6 spaces, i guess,

Comment: @ManojShenoy thats totaly not the same as your question was =(

Comment: @ManojShenoy here you are

Comment: When I run your code, the list starts after 5-6 spaces, i want that to start from left most.

Comment: @ManojShenoy ist that finaly what you want?

Comment: Click on "Run code snippet", in the display it  shows 5-6 spaces before "1."

Comment: @ManojShenoy there are no spaces, it's just a default margin

Comment: CodeiSir, U really made my day, Im sorry there was and bug with the firefox link,

Answer (score 13):

Note:- You can give the space by this code.

```html
<ol style="padding-left:1em">
  <li style="padding-left:1em">Some text</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a padding-left:25px; to the li

Comment: Did'nt work. may be since im using     
list-style-position: inside

Comment: I think you will have to remove the list-style-position, and position the ol manually